# Remove an item from an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

How do I remove items from the arraylist I know have. I know about the remove() method, but it doesn't seem to work;

```
ArrayList <String> namen = new ArrayList <> ();

    System.out.print("Voer een naam in:");

    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++){
        namen.add(in.next());
        int aantalNamen = namen.size();
        System.out.println(namen);
        System.out.println(aantalNamen);
        if(i == 10){
            namen.remove(9);
        }
    }
```

How can I change this code to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(i == 10){
        namen.remove(9);
}
```

this code not work inside the loop. because when i get 10 the loop will terminate. 
so you put remove code in outside the loop. like this

```
for (int i = 0; i<10; i++){
    namen.add(in.next());
    int aantalNamen = namen.size();
    System.out.println(namen);
    System.out.println(aantalNamen);
}
namen.remove(9);
```

Comment: it can be removed inside the loop also, just value of `i` has to be incremented

Comment: but loop contain **i < 10**

Answer (score 2):

Because of the condition `i < 10` in the `for` loop, the `if` in the `for` will never satisfy. The `for` will terminate once `i` becomes `10` and therefore, the condition `if(i == 10){` will never be true. That's why nothing is getting removed from your list.

You either need to change the condition of the `if` to `i==9` or change the condition in the for to `i <= 10`.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I change this code to make it work?

To work, you need to compare `i==9`, at `if` statement.

```
  if(i == 9){
     namen.remove(9);
   }
```